# NullPointerException in JavaFX project

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement internationalization in my javaFX project. My idea was to get all the controllers from the other fxml documents and call the method `loadLang` in each of them when the language is changed. I'm having some trouble though with getting the controllers. Here's my `changelanguage` method:

```
    @FXML
    private void handleChangeLanguage(ActionEvent event) {
    FXMLLoader myLoader;
    myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Ads.fxml"));
    AdsController ac = myLoader.<AdsController>getController();
    tabPane.getTabs();
    if (countryBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        loadLang("da");
        ac.loadLang("da");
    }
    if (countryBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        ac.loadLang("en");
        loadLang("en");
    }
        //translate them to selected language
}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at `ac.loadLang("en");`. I'm pretty sure it's because it didn't obtain the controller of `AdsController.fxml` properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Add exception trace.

Comment: That probably means method `myLoader.<AdsController>getController()` returns null

Comment: I figured as much. Can you tell me why?

Comment: If this is a duplicate, can you tell me where this question has been answered? Because i can't find it.